# Where are the liferay database upgrade scripts located for oracle db?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, liferay

I am in the process of updating liferay 5.2.3 to liferay 6.1.1. but i am getting alot of problems using the auto database updater. So i am trying to manually update the database.

The problem is that i can only find the Microsoft SQL server .sql files. The oracle db files are no where to be found. I found a few oracle sql files on http://haitianschoolwithoutborders.org/liferay/. But they only go up to version 6.0.1.

All the sql files for microsoft sql server are found in the sql folder when you download the liferay source. But there are no sql files for other databases inside the liferay source.

Does anyone know where i can find the database upgrade files for the oracle database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `liferay-portal-db-upgrade-6.1.1-ce-ga2-20120731132656558.zip` bundled application.

It's not easy to migrate from `5.2.3 to 6.1.1`, maybe it's better to have an intermediate step with `6.06` version.
Use always the `liferay-portal-db-upgrade-x.x.x.` It's the best way.

Comment: I don't think it's possible at all to migrate directly from 5.2 to 6.1. All documentation clearly says you can only migrate from one version to the next at a time (5.2 -> 6.0 -> 6.1)

Answer (score 0):

Ah i have found the update scripts on https://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-portal/available-releases.